# Scaling CSS Tile Grid with min width and max width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to make a grid in CSS with tiles that will not be smaller than 200px, but not be larger than 400px.  But i want them to scale in between those percentages, right now they stay maxed at 400 and if you shrink the window, they just drop down to the next line.  I'd rather have them both shrink to 350px and still fit, or 300px instead of just wrapping.  thx in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">

    .boxes{
        min-width: 200px;
        max-width: 400px;
        width: auto;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: #dedede;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 20px;     
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 15px;

    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="boxes">Aenean malesuada feugiat scelerisque. Aliquam ultricies sem nunc, id tempus est. Donec et dui sem. Donec et diam nunc. Nullam vel pulvinar dui. In aliquet feugiat magna vel eleifend. Suspendisse fermentum tincidunt urna, ut sagittis enim blandit non. In placerat, libero et convallis molestie, eros ipsum imperdiet nisi, quis cursus mi dolor eu elit.</div>
<div class="boxes">Aenean malesuada feugiat scelerisque. Aliquam ultricies sem nunc, id tempus est. Donec et dui sem. Donec et diam nunc. Nullam vel pulvinar dui. In aliquet feugiat magna vel eleifend. Suspendisse fermentum tincidunt urna, ut sagittis enim blandit non. In placerat, libero et convallis molestie, eros ipsum imperdiet nisi, quis cursus mi dolor eu elit.</div>
<div class="boxes">Aenean malesuada feugiat scelerisque. Aliquam ultricies sem nunc, id tempus est. Donec et dui sem. Donec et diam nunc. Nullam vel pulvinar dui. In aliquet feugiat magna vel eleifend. Suspendisse fermentum tincidunt urna, ut sagittis enim blandit non. In placerat, libero et convallis molestie, eros ipsum imperdiet nisi, quis cursus mi dolor eu elit.</div>
<div class="boxes">Aenean malesuada feugiat scelerisque. Aliquam ultricies sem nunc, id tempus est. Donec et dui sem. Donec et diam nunc. Nullam vel pulvinar dui. In aliquet feugiat magna vel eleifend. Suspendisse fermentum tincidunt urna, ut sagittis enim blandit non. In placerat, libero et convallis molestie, eros ipsum imperdiet nisi, quis cursus mi dolor eu elit.</div>
<div class="boxes">Aenean malesuada feugiat scelerisque. Aliquam ultricies sem nunc, id tempus est. Donec et dui sem. Donec et diam nunc. Nullam vel pulvinar dui. In aliquet feugiat magna vel eleifend. Suspendisse fermentum tincidunt urna, ut sagittis enim blandit non. In placerat, libero et convallis molestie, eros ipsum imperdiet nisi, quis cursus mi dolor eu elit.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your boxes in a single parent div, and use `display: table` on the parent and `display: table-cell` on the children.

Like this:

```
.boxes {
  max-width: 400px;
  min-width: 200px;
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #dedede;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  display: table-cell;
}
.boxes-parent {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 15px; /* for spacing boxes apart */
}
```